# How to get second largest or third largest entry from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, max

Can anyone please tell me how to find out the **N th largest entry from a table** in Oracle?

*Like for largest we can use* MAX(column_name) *is there any efficient way to find nth largest also*?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT some_column, 
         row_number() over (order by your_sort_column desc) as row_num
  FROM some_table
) t
WHERE row_num = 3
```

If you expect more than one row to have the same value in `your_sort_column` you can also use the rank() function

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT some_column, 
         rank() over (order by your_sort_column desc) as row_rank
  FROM some_table
) t
WHERE row_rank = 3
```

This migh return more than one row..

Comment: +1: Only caveat is analytic functions are supported on 9i+.  And DENSE_RANK might be a better choice than RANK, depending on needs.

Comment: Not true. Analytical functions were available in 8i: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a85397/function.htm#81409. But 8i and 9i are de-supported anyway. So there is no reason to post answers covering those versions if not explicitely mentioned

Answer (score 6):

You can find the Nth largest value of a column by using the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName a 
WHERE n = (
           SELECT count( DISTINCT (b.ColumnName) )
           FROM TableName b 
           WHERE a.ColumnName <= b.ColumnName 
          );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 5):

I think the below query will work to find the second highest record with **NOT IN**.

```
SELECT MAX( userId )
FROM table 
WHERE userId NOT IN ( 
                      SELECT MAX( userId )
                      FROM table
                    );
```

simple and useful...

Answer (score 1):

To get second largest salary use this:

```
select salary from 
  (select s2.salary,rownum rm from
     (select distinct salary from employees order by salary desc)
  s2 where rownum<=2)
where rm >= 2
```

Comment: works perfectly but still I am not understand why query is not working after modifying like below

MODIFIED:
select s2.salary,rownum rm from
     (select distinct salary from employees order by salary desc)
  s2 where rm<=2

Answer (score 1):

It works for second highest salary,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY field_name` DESC LIMIT 1 , 1 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `ORDER BY column name` and then `LIMIT 1,1` to get the second one

**edit**

Whoops, didn't see the Oracle tag, sorry.
`ORDER BY column name WHERE ROWNUM = 2` should work better.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support LIMIT.

Comment: "WHERE ROWNUM = 2" will never return any rows.

Comment: From http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm: "Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer are always false."  You have to alias ROWNUM and then use that alias instead of ROWNUM.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT (a.sal) FROM EMP A WHERE &N = (
  SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT (b.sal)) FROM EMP B WHERE a.sal<=b.sal
);
```

Replace `&N` with you desired number. For example, `2` will give you the second largest salary.

If you are using PL/SQL, just execute the statement. It will prompt for N.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT Sal FROM Tab ORDER BY Sal DESC LIMIT 2,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 id,[Password] 
FROM Users_changepassword 
WHERE [UserId] = 3
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sql where Row_number() function of the oracle sql is used

```
select column_name from (
 select column_name ,  
row_number() over (order by column_name  desc) as  row_num  
from table_Name ) tablex
where row_num =3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee
WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CONNECT BY PRIOR` by:

```
CREATE TABLE t(i INT, sal INT);
INSERT INTO t(i, sal)
SELECT 1,100 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 2,100 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 3,200 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 4,500 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 5,1000 FROM dual;
```

Query:

```
SELECT level, MAX(sal) AS sal
FROM t
--WHERE level = 2 -- set position here
CONNECT BY prior sal > sal
GROUP BY level
ORDER BY level;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c03c8df808409fb31ed83bf33c46c82d)**

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2b74027e596ac06f43461c1d79193c7c)**

---

**EDIT:**

Second approach is to use `NTH_VALUE` analytic function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NTH_VALUE(sal, 2) OVER(ORDER BY sal DESC
       ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM t;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo3](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3c2ec7d9b4996e040dde4301a15ca85d)**