# find second (or nth) latest value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've referred [How to get second largest or third largest entry from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483222/how-to-get-second-largest-or-third-largest-entry-from-a-table), but it only returns by looking through **max** value.

but here I need an sql query which uses max value of another field (here id which is a sequence).

Here is the table my_test
[image]

I need to get second largest unique value of **sent_by**, ie., **100** according through **id**

my query doesn't seems good, I've tried

```
SELECT sent_by
FROM MY_TEST
WHERE id =
     (SELECT MAX(id)
     FROM MY_TEST
     WHERE id NOT IN
          (SELECT id
          FROM MY_TEST
          WHERE sent_by =(SELECT sent_by FROM my_test WHERE id =(SELECT MAX(id) FROM MY_TEST))
          )
     ); -- results 100
```

is there any other easy way to get the required? and how about if i need to get the 3rd?

### **editing**

Here i'll update my question to make you more clear.

let us assume the given table is details of message transactions.
let id be unique and is (sequence), sent_by is inserted with the individual's / person's id (like user_id).
the sent_by column may / may not inserted with multiple rows with same user_id.

if i need to take latest sent_by value:
i can query

```
select sent_by from my_test where id= (select max(id) from my_test);-- to get 60
```

my question is to take the second latest sent_by value:
(in the given table ,

```
the 2nd latest sent_by value should be 100, as id 8, 9, 10 are same sent_by values
the 3rd latest sent_by value should be 4, 
the 4th latest sent_by value should be 3
```

)

hope the question is clear now.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Try using distinct of the row and sort by desc and select the second row.

Comment: It's not clear why [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4483657/1083652) you've refered to isn't good. All you need to do is specify in the `your_sort_column` part the 2 columns - `SENT_BY, ID`

Comment: Please check with the updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right, then try something like this:

```
select * 
from(
  select sent_by, row_number() over (order by sent_by desc, id asc) row_num
  from MY_TEST) t
where row_num = 2 -- or 3 ... n
```

---

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
select * 
from(
  select sent_by, 
         rank() over (order by max(id) desc)  rk
   from MY_TEST
  group by sent_by) t
where rk = 2 -- or 3 .. n
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d059/45)

Comment: @ A.B.Cade, I've already checked with this, Please check the updated question, to make you the question more clear

Comment: Well, that's too a wonderful answer. and as mixed query of techdo's answer. Thanks for a good query.

Comment: That's a great answer... enriches my knowledge!

Comment: @ A.B.Cade, how would I get the id of that corresponding rank? say  7 for rk = 2, 5 for rk = 3 etc. I've used sub-query by using max(), is there any other good way? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To find the second value, try:

```
select * from(
  SELECT sent_by, row_number() over (order by sent_by desc) RNum
  FROM MY_TEST
  )x
WHERE RNum =2
```

for third

```
select * from(
  SELECT sent_by, row_number() over (order by sent_by desc) RNum
  FROM MY_TEST
  )x
WHERE RNum =3
```

Yes... Now this makes a different question. Please check my try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SENT_BY FROM(
  select ID, SENT_BY,  dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY MaxID DESC) RNum FROM(
    SELECT ID, SENT_BY, max(ID) over (partition by sent_by order by ID desc) MaxID
    FROM MY_TEST
  )x
)xx where RNum=3
```

Comment: my question is not at all doing with order by sent_by column,
i'll update my to question to make you clear, 
as in my requirement,  i need the 3rd latest value as 4.

Answer (score 0):

Analytic functions. ROW_NUMBER() OVER()
[NTH_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions112.htm)

Answer (score 0):

method 1:

```
select sent_by, rownum, from my_test where(rowid,0) in (select rowid, mod(rownum,4) from my_test);
```

this would return every 4th row. If you want random rows replace subquery with rownums in an in clause.

method 2:

```
select sent_by, rownum from (select sent_by , rownum  from MY_TEST) v1 where mod(v1.rownum,4)=0;
```

Method 3:

```
select sent_by, rownum, from my_test group by sent_by, rownum having mod(rownum,n)=0 or rownum=2-n
```

with any of these methods to select say 5th and 9th rows this could change 1st method to the following

```
select sent_by, rownum, from my_test where rownum in(5,9);
```

Comment: ,at first , the question is not for selecting the nth row, instead it should take nth latest row, so it should works perfectly only with id, but not with rowid, or rownum.