# Phantom LONG datatype is crashing my SQL code - ORA-00997

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following code which is supposed to find each column in a database and ouptput the column name, table name, data type, number of null values, and number of rows.

The problem that I run into is that when I run it, it runs for about two minutes, and then complains about an 'illegal use of LONG datatype', but I am not using any LONG here.

If I edit my search to only select WHERE rownum < 100 (commented out in the following code), it works perfectly. Additionally, if I only do the SELECT statement, it runs just fine and outputs all of the correct SQL statements. (about 18000 of them) So I am guessing that the error is in the loop somewhere.

Any guidance on how to fix this?

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    declare
       myCol1 varchar2(1000);
       myCol2 varchar2(1000);
       myCol3 varchar2(1000);
       myCol4 number;
       myCol5 number;
     begin
       for line in
       (
         SELECT
             'SELECT ''' || atc.column_name || ''', ''' || atc.table_name || ''', ''' || atc.data_type || ''', 
         SUM(CASE WHEN temp.'|| atc.column_name || ' IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)           "Filled Values", 
             COUNT(temp.' || atc.column_name || ') "Total Records" 
             FROM all_tab_columns atc 
             JOIN '|| atc.table_name || ' temp ON atc.column_name = ''' || 
             atc.column_name ||''' AND atc.table_name = ''' || atc.table_name || '''' AS SQLRow 
         FROM all_tab_columns atc --WHERE rownum < 100
       )
       loop
          execute immediate line.Sqlrow into myCol1, myCol2, myCol3, myCol4, myCol5;
          INSERT INTO results VALUES (myCol1, myCol2, myCol3, myCol4, myCol5);
       end loop;


     end;
     SELECT * FROM results;

     /
```

Comment: Could one of your number of X (rows, null values) -- be so high it's now considered a long datatype being  and into 64 bit integer?   After looking at your count holders, that can't be - they're declared as `number` which is the [basic container for all kinds of numbers in Oracle.][1]


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313

Comment: [This Link](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=430) might help you as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the tables being picked up has a `LONG` column. Your static code isn't referring to it directly, but the dynamic SQL you're generating is, e.g.

```
SELECT 'SQL_TEXT', 'OL$', 'LONG', 
     SUM(CASE WHEN temp.SQL_TEXT IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) "Filled Values", 
         COUNT(temp.SQL_TEXT) "Total Records" 
         FROM all_tab_columns atc 
         JOIN OL$ temp ON atc.column_name = 'SQL_TEXT' AND atc.table_name = 'OL$'
```

It's complaining about the `COUNT`. You can't apply aggregates, even something that seems as simple as a count, to a `LONG` column. Or any built-in function; from [the data types documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00201):

> In addition, LONG columns cannot appear in these parts of SQL
>   statements:
>
> - GROUP BY clauses, ORDER BY clauses, or CONNECT BY clauses or with the DISTINCT operator in SELECT statements
> - The UNIQUE operator of a SELECT statement
> - The column list of a CREATE CLUSTER statement
> - The CLUSTER clause of a CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW statement
> - SQL built-in functions, expressions, or conditions
>
> ...

The `ROWNUM` filter just happens to be stopping before it encounters any `LONG` columns in the data dictionary.

To run this for everything else you'd need to exclude `LONG` columns from your query. You might want to restrict it you selected schemas though; reporting the data types of system tables/columns seems a little odd.

I'm not sure why you're joining back to `all_tab_columns` in your generated query. This would get the same result (for a column with a different data type in the same table):

```
SELECT 'SPARE2', 'OL$', 'VARCHAR2', 
     SUM(CASE WHEN temp."SPARE2" IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), 
     COUNT(temp."SPARE2")
     FROM SYSTEM."OL$" temp
```

`COUNT` only counts non-null values, so it'll give you the same result as the `SUM` (except the sum gives null if the table is empty). If you want to count all rows then count a constant, not the column name. So instead you could do:

```
SELECT 'SPARE2', 'OL$', 'VARCHAR2', 
     COUNT(temp."SPARE2"),
     COUNT(1)
     FROM SYSTEM."OL$" temp
```

You can give a null result for LONG and LOB values, rather than skipping those columns altogether, by changing the dynamic query based on the data type. You might also want to quote all the identifiers just in case you have mixed case or other problems:

```
   for line in (
     SELECT
         'SELECT ''' || atc.column_name || ''', '
           || '''' || atc.table_name || ''', '
           || '''' || atc.data_type || ''', '
           || CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('LONG', 'CLOB', 'BLOB') THEN 'NULL'
             ELSE 'COUNT(temp."' || atc.column_name || '")' END || ', '
           || 'COUNT(1) '
         || 'FROM '|| atc.owner || '."' || atc.table_name || '" temp ' AS SQLRow 
    FROM all_tab_columns atc 
    WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM') -- and others
   ) loop
```

Or use your `SUM` version if you want to get the not-null count for those too, I suppose, but with `NVL` so it reports zero for empty tables.

Comment: `select * from all_tab_columns where data_type='LONG';` should identify it!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar - it should, but I was thinking of something more generic like adding `and data_type != 'LONG'` to the cursor query.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response Alex, it really helped a lot.

Comment: I am testing my code to make sure that everything is working properly and I noticed that if I don't include the first row, it won't output anything. For example i wanted to run it `WHERE rownum BETWEEN 100 and 200` because I believe the first LONG is somewhere in there, but it just responded with no rows selected. Do you know what may be causing this? (`WHERE rownum BETWEEN 1 and 200` works just fine)

Comment: @TaiwanTimmy - that should be a new question, but it would be a duplicate, so I'll just [point you to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/855446/266304).

Comment: If you want to use a range you can use a subquery; [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4483657/266304) would work.